# Getting extra blank object while displaying the jquery ajax return data

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I am using a jquery ajax function to retrieve data from worpdress post-meta table. My ajax call back is working fine, and getting result. here it is how i use my call back `echo json_encode($dd);`. `$dd` is an array of data from database, same code I tested and getting proper result without ajax.

So here is the issue, when I use this return data in ajax success function like this

```
 $.each(datax, function(key, val) {
     $('ul#wasteP').append('<li>'+val+'</li>');
});
```

I am getting all the data as intended, but with One extra blank 'li', I cant figure it out why, as I said when I use the Ajax Call back function in a seperate page and use `print_r` I could not see an extra blank field or something.

Even this `alert(Object.keys(data).length);` returns correct count for the returned data, for example I am getting 4 as the data count, but while printing there is an extra 5th element, with no data in that.

Why am I getting the extra element and how can I remove it?

Comment: Try `console.log(val)` before append and check console.

Comment: i did, same, I am getting a blank row in console after the actual last element

Comment: Well you could do `if (val) { /* append li */}` as a quick and dirty solution

Comment: otherwise what key does the empty val have?

Comment: Does the JSON already have a property named `length`? If so, then `each` may not work properly.

Comment: try this `datax.forEach(function(el){ $('ul#wasteP').append('<li>' + el + '</li>'); })`

Comment: @errnesto - thanx for that dirty one, any how that's the only one solution i got so far that works.

Comment: @errnesto - if i replace val with key i get all keys in li without any blank li, but if i add val then this extra black li getting, what might be the reason. I am doing some thing like this --  $('ul#wasteP').append('<li><label><input type="radio" value="'+key+'" name="typeInt" rel="1" class="nobreak" >'+val+'</label></li>');  if i replace label as key, there is no extras, but if it is val then ....